# ionic3 ios13 InAppbrowser crash

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm creating ios13 app in Ionic3.

But ios13Beta2 is not working in InAppBrowser.

so select param '_blank', this app is crash.

This is error detail.

> [TraitCollection] Class _UIFullscreenPresentationController overrides
>   the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying
>   to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.

My ionic environment

**Ionic:**

```
Ionic CLI : 5.0.3 
Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.6
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
```

**Cordova:**

```
Cordova CLI : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : ios 5.0.1
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 14 other plugins)
```

**Utility:**

```
cordova-res : not installed
native-run : not installed
```

**System:**

```
ios-sim : 8.0.1
NodeJS : v12.4.0
npm : 6.9.0
OS : macOS Catalina
Xcode : Xcode 11.0 Build version 11M337n
```

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue 
but finally got it resolved by downgrading the WKView

It's one of the temporary solutions until we are able to get a concrete one.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/wkwebview/

you can do it by adding this in config.xml

`<platform name="ios">
        <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" />`

Comment: Using UIWebView instead of WKWebView is not really a solution

Comment: `ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs.`